# How to Display redirect()->to()->with() in view (CI4)

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I am trying to set a flashdata in redirect but it's not getting picked up so I turn to `redirect()->to()->with()` function. However, I don't know how to call it in my view. I tried copying how it's done in Laravel but it's not working.

Here's my redirect code:

> `return redirect()->to(base_url('categories'))->with('msg', 'You are not allowed to access that category.');`

What I try in my view:

> `if(session()->has('msg')){ echo session()->get('msg'); }`

I've been looking for it for hours but can't find any in the documentation. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you using laravel or codeigniter

Comment: @chyke007 I'm using codeigniter 4

Comment: Can you try checking for existing session with $session->has('msg');

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is just a cache thing or something else but I removed, updated something, then put back my old code and it worked.

In my controller:

```
$session->setFlashdata('success', false);
$session->setFlashdata('msg', 'You are not allowed to access that category.');
$session->setFlashdata('alert', 'alert-warning');
return redirect()->to(base_url('courses'));
```

In my view:

```
<?php
    if($session->getFlashdata('msg') != ''){
  ?>
  <div class="alert <?= $session->getFlashdata('alert') ?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <span class="text-start mb-0"><?= $session->getFlashdata('msg') ?></span>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close login-btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <?php    
    }
  ?>
```

I also discovered that using `with()` is the same as calling `getFlashdata` in view:

```
return redirect()->to(base_url('courses'))->with('msg', 'You are not allowed to access that category.');
```